# Организация одинаковой верстки отдаваемой сервером в php и формируемой динамически на клиенте в js

Tags: javascript, php, html, вёрстка

Подскажите как правильно организовать.

Есть определенная верстка, которая отдается сервером в виде html элемента, и эта же верстка может меняться динамически на странице скриптом после ajax-запроса.

В первом случае html формируется в файлах php, во втором - в js-скриптах. Как правильно это организовать, чтобы верстка не отличалась.

- просто помнить разработчику что этот блок html формируется в разных местах
- может отдавать в ajax-запросе готовый html, который также формируется в файлах view

может есть какая-то общая практика

**updated**:
Пример - сервер отдает список моделей при первом формировании страницы::

```
<ul class="list">
<li class="fruit" data-attr="alpha">
    <a href="#">
        <img src=""/>
        <div>
            apple
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="fruit" data-attr="beta">
    <a href="#">
        <img src=""/>
        <div>
            orange
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
...
```

получаю данные ajax запросом

```
{
    "gamma": "pineapple",
    "delta": "cherry"
}
```

динамически создаю или добавляю новые dom-элементы на стороне клиента

```
$.each(obj, function(i, $val)
{
    var li = $('<li>');
    $('<li>', { class: 'fruit' })
    .append(
        $('<a>', { href: '#' })
        .append(
            $('<img>', { src: '' })
            )
        .append(
            $('<div>', { text: 'somefruit' })
            )
        )
    .appendTo('ul.list');
});
```

**updated 2:**
На стороне php могут быть условия в верстке, которые например как этот

```
if( isset($imgSrc) ){?>
    <img src="<?php echo $imgSrc?>"/>
<?}
else{?>
    <span><?php echo $name?></span>
<?}
```

Вопрос в том, какие есть практики для поддержания вот таких dom-структур идентичными и на стороне php и на стороне js

Comment: Так верстка меняется же на клиенте, после Ajax-запроса... и она может отличаться...что тут организовывать? Непонятно. Соответственно, что бэк отдаст, то клиент и отрисует

Comment: Общая практика это mvc. Но ведь вёрстка может метяться на фронте не просто так?

Comment: обновил вопрос, наверное сначала не до конца объяснил

Answer (score 0):

Я бы делал так:нужным элементам назначил уникальные аттрибуты

```
<ul class="list" id="template">
<li class="fruit" data-attr="alpha">
    <a href="#" class='link'>
        <img src=""/ class='img'>
        <div class='text'>
            apple
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="fruit" data-attr="beta">
    <a href="#">
        <img src=""/>
        <div>
            orange
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

После получения ответа от сервера клонировал бы шаблон и потом внутрь него, по уникальным аттрибутам, подставлял значения:

```
const template = document.getElementById('template').firstChildren;
const clone = template.cloneNode(deep);
const link = clone.querySelector('.link');
link.href = someHref;
const img = clone.querySelector('.img');
img.src = someSrc;
```

Comment: Интересный вариант, но в моем случае он не подходит, потому что в верстке на стороне сервера есть условия, например, если в элементе списка нету изображения я возвращаю span с аббревиатурой из названия (обновил в вопросе). Если в json придет элемент с изображеним, а у меня в html первым элементом для клонирования будет элемент без изображения, тогда копирование пройдет неправильно. В любом случае спасибо.